# deserialize string to c# object using newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a json string like below

```
value = {
    {
        "Type": "P1",    
        "IsAvailable": "1",  
        "Logics": {
            "ID": "B",
            "ID": "X",
            "ID": "B"
        }
    }
}
```

It should be deserizlized to C# class object like below

```
public class CatType
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Logic
{
    public string ID{ get; set; }
}
```

When I am trying to deserialize by using below statement I am getting exception

```
CatType _catType= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CatType >(value.ToString());
```

What needs to be done to succesfully deserialize object?

I tried different way to resolve the issue nothing worked out

Comment: `i am getting exception` Which exception?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. _The most common cause of this is invalid JSON, and a [mcve] will help us spot that faster._

Comment: Is the JSON string equal to what you posted exactly? If so, that is not valid JSON. Try to validate it in https://jsonlint.com/ and you'll see what I mean. Remove `value=` from the string.

Comment: How do you deserialize it ? Which exception are you getting. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

Your classes are not correct for that json type.  You need to have a collection of Logic inside of the CatType for one.  Also the IsAvailable is not present in CatType. The structure appears to be something more like this.

```
public class CatType
{
    public string Type { get; set; } 
    public string IsAvailable { get; set; }
    public List<Logic> Logics { get; set; }
}

public class Logic
{
    public string ID{ get; set; }
}
```

Your json is also invalid.  The Logics object has 3 properties with the name ID which is not allowed.  It should be an array type. Like so

```
value={
    {
        "Type": "P1",    
        "IsAvailable": "1",  
        "Logics": [
            "ID": "B",
            "ID": "X",
            "ID": "B"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have modified and tried i am getting below exception

Comment: It 's worked. Thanks